# Why does Mac running Ventura OS now insist on using FN key to deliver function keys?

Tags: macbook-pro, ventura

For some reason, the latest Mac OS - unprompted - insists that I press the FN key for the functionality that is displayed on functions. Why? I want the functions for brightness or volume set as default. How do I do that? And how do I change back permanently?

Answer (score 4):

`System Settings | Keyboard | Keyboard Shortcuts | Function Keys` provides a switch for what you need.

This behaviour is not new to Ventura. It has been in macOS since dual use Fn keys first appeared.